# Can Microsoft Project be used without Sharepoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

Is MS Sharepoint server required to use MS Project and what is the relation between them? I need only project server is it possible to use only MS Project server without Sharepoint server or can I manage it with sharepoint services?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Project Server 2010 (you didn't specify the version so I'll assume you meant the latest), no.

[> Microsoft Project Server 2010 is built on Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/project-server-2010-product-guide.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.  Project Server 2007 is built on SharePoint Services (WSS) and requires it but if the follow on question is: should you use your MOSS SharePoint farm (With other sharepoint apps) to support project the answer would be no.   Project 2010 is much more tightly integrated with MOSS 2010 and is more Dependant on it.    Here are the software requirements for Project Server 2010 [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee683978.aspx#section8)

Here is a [link](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=214) from a person who explains the issue of integrating Project server into a SharePoint farm with locally designed apps.  This is focused on Project server 2007 so YMMV in the 2010 space.   The main issue is that if you have SharePoint folks in your space, they will want to make changes and upgrade faster than the project server software LifeCycle.

So...you need SharePoint but it is recommended that you deploy a standalone instance for project server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Project stand alone, but you'll have to update the data manually.

With a link to something like Sharepoint where you track the actual time taken for tasks/work items then the data can be updated automatically and your project gets updated too.